# Handsontable using custom formula

Tags: javascript, handsontable

How can i use custom cell formula with handsontable? (like SUM, AVERAGE etc.)

```
=CUSTOM_FUNCTION(5, "Value")
```

and custom function is:

```
function CUSTOM_FUNCTION(id, key) {
    //returns record[key] where record.id == id
    return _.find(GlobalObject, function(r){ return r.id == id; })[key];
}
```